# Purpose of a universal selector in css

Tags: css

I have the following piece of code:

```
.x-border-box,
.x-border-box *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Now my question is, what is the * doing there?

As per http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html , it matches any element.

whether it is there or not DOES seem to have some impact on my code though...

Comment: I don't get it. You already know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does exactly what you said: It matches all descendants of `.x-border-box`.

Comment: Wont `.x-border-box` also match all descendants though, making the `.x-border-box,
.x-border-box *` redundant?

Comment: No, it's not redundant, because `box-sizing` is a property that's not inherited to descendants. MDN always has good info on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing. So the two selectors are neccessary, one to style `x-border-box` and the other to style all of its descendants.